# La « hardiesse de poète » est-elle davantage qu'une simple licence ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes

> **Hardiesse** de poète : *Souvenirs* FEUX chez VERLAINE, *Dédicaces*,
>   LVII, avec une place anormale (§ 324, a). [Le ms. nous dit A. Kies,
>   est peu net.]
>
> *Feu* après le nom est une **liberté** de poète : *Aux premières heures bleues / Se détruira-t-elle comme les fleurs* FEUES... (RIMBAUD,
>   *Illum.*, Est-elle almée ?)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>,
>   extraits de § 324 a, 552 b, je souligne ]

On a le mot [*hardiesse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hardiesse) qui renvoie probablement à [*hardi*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hardi) (I A 2) « qui est au-dessus des règles communes; qui est hasardé, audacieux avec bonheur » (TLFi) alors qu'on semble parler d'une simple *licence* dans ce contexte au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hardiesse). Qu'en est-il ?

Peut-on confirmer le sens de *hardiesse* (*de poète*) généralement ainsi que dans l'exemple : pourquoi y comprendrait-on ou non une différence d'avec *liberté* et quelle serait-elle le cas échéant ?

Answer (score 1):

Le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/hardiesse?page=1) ne laisse aucun doute, ce terme est employé pour « licence ».

> 4. Par méton. Souvent au pluriel. Parole, action hardie. Se permettre une hardiesse, des hardiesses. Se dit notamment des licences prises par un écrivain, un artiste. Des hardiesses de style.

Le terme [licence](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/licence) est alors  il me semble la clé à cette question de savoir si le terme « hardiesse » implique autre chose que la notion stricte de licence dans le domaine de la littérature.

De la définition de « licence » au « C » dans le TLi

> C. LITT., et domaine des arts. Liberté que prend un écrivain, un artiste ou qui lui est laissée par l'usage, d'enfreindre certaines habitudes, certaines règles de son art; ce qui en résulte.
>   POÉT. Faculté laissée au poète d'utiliser une forme, une construction, une prosodie, une prononciation qui n'est pas conforme à l'usage habituel; son résultat (d'apr. MAR. Lex. 1951).
>    Licence grammaticale, poétique. La poésie populaire est le pays de la licence, de toutes les licences (GOURMONT, Esthét. lang. fr., 1899, p. 266).

on dégage qu'appliqué à l'art poétique la licence est une liberté prise  seulement avec les formes de l'expression.

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/licence) propose une définition qui parait tout aussi étroite.

> (Poésie) Toute liberté que le poète se donne dans ses vers contre la règle et [l’usage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/usage) ordinaire. (Licence poétique)

On trouve le terme assez courant « hardiesse littéraire »; par exemple, dans la [caractérisation suivante](https://books.google.fr/books?id=j8smDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22hardiesse+litt%C3%A9raire%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiqNSzjqvnAhXDx4UKHRs0AhwQ6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=%22hardiesse%20litt%C3%A9raire%22&f=false) de l'œuvre de Dumas fils elle est appliquée au théâtre où les licences habituelles qui sont celles du poète ne sont pas d'habitude une matière à discussion. On voit donc que par « hardiesse » on peut entendre quelque chose de plus et cela n'est plus dans le domaine relativement étroit de conventions linguistiques mais dans le domaine beaucoup plus vaste des vues sur le sujet à laquelle est consacrée une œuvre.

> Si un auteur dramatique, comme M. Alexandre Dumas fils, fait encore avec succès des pièces à thèses, ce sont précisément ces thèses qu'on lui reproche, et si on lui pardonne c'est en faveur de sa hardiesse littéraire et aussi de sa hardiesse morale, de son mépris des conventions théâtrales, et de certaines conventions sociales qui donnent à sa morale quelque chose du piquant de l'immoralité.

L'[example](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hy4602-ajGMC&pg=PA1069&dq=%22hardiesse+litt%C3%A9raire%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiqNSzjqvnAhXDx4UKHRs0AhwQ6AEIUjAF#v=onepage&q=%22hardiesse%20litt%C3%A9raire%22&f=false) d'utilisation suivante montre clairement que c'est une caractérisation possible d'un travail de poète qui le situe sur le plan de son manque adhérence aux conventions, mais dans une perspective plus vaste que celle des convention linguistiques, celle des conventions de forme structurelle et de forme de fond, c'est à dire par exemple des conventions telles que celles de la règle des trois unités dans le théâtre classique.

[image]

Il y a lieu de croire que cette hardiesse littéraire est aussi une licence de poète dans le cas présent.

On est donc enclin à se rabattre sur la définition générale du  [TLFi, **II A 2 a)**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hardiesse) qui renvoie à « hardi **I A 2** »,

> « II. − P. méton., le plus souvent au plur. Ce qui est hardi (acte, réalisation, comportement, parole, écrit). 
>   Avoir, oser, se permettre une, des hardiesse(s).
>
> A. − [Avec une valeur laudative]
>   2. [Correspond à hardi I A 2]
>   a) Le plus cour., domaine de la vie intellectuelle.
>
> - Un assez bon nombre de nos poètes ayant écrit en prose, le style ordinaire en a reçu un éclat et des hardiesses qu'il n'aurait point eus sans eux (Joubert, Pensées, t. 2, 1824, p. 81).
> - Laisse à d'autres les ingéniosités de style, les hardiesses de syntaxe, la poursuite des épithètes rares (Martin du G., Souv. autobiogr.,1955, p. lxxx) :
> - Il y a des auteurs originaux dont la moindre hardiesse révolte parce qu'ils n'ont pas d'abord flatté les goûts du public et ne lui ont pas servi les lieux communs auxquels il est habitué... Proust, Swann,1913, p. 266. »,

qui dans les deux premiers exemples cités montre que le terme « hardiesse » est au moins utile à caractériser la nature de l'usage et qui par le mot « écrit » ([TLFi, écrit², **B 1.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9crit)), lequel porte sur la teneur du texte, tend à faire penser que quelque chose autre que la forme linguistique est visé.

À mon avis, c'est un terme qui apparemment englobe l'idée de liberté prise sur les conventions de l'usage et donc un terme applicable dans le cas d'une syntaxe inhabituelle, mais qui permet de considérer cette liberté  plus généralement selon  l'idée *d'adhésion à des actes de ruptures avec le gout accepté*, cette idée incluant la possibilité d'un détachement de certaines pratiques que l'on ne considère pas aussi catégoriquement comme étant impossible à enfreindre que celles de la linguistique et avec lesquelles on ne prend pas vraiment des libertés (un terme un peu fort) et au plus que l'on approche avec une certaine licence; on peut toujours parler de licence bien que pas de licence poétique me semble-t-il.

Comment: Non, le dictionnaire de l'Ac. laisse place au doute : « 3. Originalité, audace dans la conception ou l'exécution d'un ouvrage de l'esprit ou d'un ouvrage de l'art. La hardiesse d'une image. _La hardiesse de l'expression, du style_. », cette acception au singulier précède celle surtout au pluriel sur laquelle tu fais reposer l'ensemble de ta réponse, ce qui semble périlleux. Par ailleurs LBU14 au par. 14 b met en contexte le terme avec d'autres pour ce qui est de l'emploi là à tout le moins. Je ne dis pas que ça veuille dire autre chose que licence mais pas sur la base de l'argument initial.